# Android Studio: other controls disappear when ExpandableListView shows

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a TableLayout containing 3 rows:

- 1st row: A label
- 2nd row: A `RelativeLayout` with 2 `EditTexts` and a
  `Button`
- 3rd row: An `ExpandableListView`

I'm filling the list through an `AsyncTask`. It's working OK, the list is showing the records, however, when it does, the controls in the 2nd row disappear.

It happens exactly after I call:

```
expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

This is my layout

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Los 5 productos maś vendidos en la web"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dateFrom"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:editable="false"
                android:background="#d9fcff"
                android:text="2015-10-01"
                android:height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:width="140dp"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/dateTo" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dateTo"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:editable="false"
                android:background="#eafccf"
                android:text="2015-10-30"
                android:height="40dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:width="140dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="52dp" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="OK"
                android:id="@+id/button12"
                android:width="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.08"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
            android:layout_weight="1.04"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

In the Activity's onCreate method I call:

```
new RetrieveFeedTask(this).execute();
```

Whose onPostExecute code is:

```
activityStats.setProductsList(listDataHeader, listDataChild);
```

And that setProductsList method is:

```
public void setProductsList(List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild) {
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

Comment: I think we need to see more code/layouts.

Comment: post the xml code here.  Ideally you should be using the lisview's header to put things above the listview